# Protractor tests break when adding comments

Tags: protractor

Some protractor tests are breaking when I include a comment beside them or a
 `.then(() => console.log("hello"))` statement beside a promise element.

**Works:**

```
menuIcon.click().then(function () { expect(isWorking).toBeTruthy(); });
```

**Doesn't work:**

```
menuIcon.click().then(function () { expect(isWorking).toBeTruthy(); }).then(() => console.log('Verified menu is working');
```

**Error:**

> Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

However, using different text for the comment makes this work such as:

```
menuIcon.click().then(function () { expect(isWorking).toBeTruthy(); }).then(() => console.log('comment');
```

Why might this be? Without them it always passes.

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by breaking? Are the tests no longer compiling? Are they failing? Something else? An error log would be useful

Comment: Sorry I should have been more precise. So supposing I have `menuIcon.click().then(function () { expect(isWorking).toBeTruthy(); });` where isWorking is a function which returns a promise. This works fine. However, if I then try `menuIcon.click().then(function () { expect(isWorking).toBeTruthy(); }).then(() => console.log('Verified menu is working');` it fails with this error "Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Comment: Strangely if I do `menuIcon.click().then(function () { expect(isWorking).toBeTruthy(); }).then(() => console.log('comment');` it passes. The only difference being the length of the comment.

Comment: NOW you have an interesting question. I edited your comments into the question so that the code would be easily visible to anyone else seeing the question. I'm not sure exactly what is going on though. The comment length befuddles me

Comment: Thanks for that :) Yeah, it is rather strange. Perhaps a bug in Protractor? I'm guessing the length of the statement is causing it to delay verification somewhere.